# Preventing infinite reactivity loop with DT::datatable

Tags: r, shiny, reactive-programming, dt

I'm building a shiny application where I am using `DT::datatable` to provide users a list of records in the database.  Each record is associated with a subject, and when a row is clicked in the `datatable` object, it retrieves that records data from a SQL database.

The action of retrieving all of the data and generating the UI components to display it can take about a second, or longer, depending on the server's performance at the moment.  In this delay, if the user clicks on a second row, the application enters into a reactive loop--it constantly toggles between the two rows and never stops.

Is there a mechanism to prevent this from happening?  The app given below reproduces the problem.  My ideal solution would:

1. Use the `DT::datatable` object as the interface to select the record
2. Only allow one record to be selected at a time.
3. Store the selected value in a `reactiveValues` list.  There are occasions when I need to refresh the `datatable` but I don't want to lose the selected row.
4. Either disallow additional selections while until the first selection is completed, or not recognize any additional selections while the event is processing.

In the code below, I've made a long delay on the event by resampling `mtcars` 100,000 times.  Notice how the value above the table toggles between two selected values when two rows are selected in rapid succession.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

# User Interface Definition
ui <- shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    wellPanel(
      textOutput("selected")
    ),
    DT::dataTableOutput("datatable")
  )
)

#* Server Definition
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session){
  RV <- reactiveValues(
    row = NULL
  )

  observeEvent(
    input[["datatable_rows_selected"]],
    {
      #* Create a slow event by resampling mtcars a lot.
      set.seed(pi * exp(1))
      fit <- lm(mpg ~ qsec + factor(am), 
                data = mtcars[sample(1:nrow(mtcars), 100000, replace = TRUE), ])
      RV$row <- input[["datatable_rows_selected"]]  
    }
  )

  output$selected <- 
    renderPrint(
      RV$row
    )

  output$datatable <- 
    DT::renderDataTable({
      rownames(mtcars) <- NULL
      DT::datatable(mtcars,
                    selection = list(mode = "single",
                                     target = "row",
                                     selected = RV$row)
      )
    })
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

### Follow up

Based on @warmoverflow's comment, I wrote up the code below. It let's me stop the loop.  But it also disables the row selection feature.  So far, the only way I've found to restore it without creating the initial problem is to use an action button.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

# User Interface Definition
ui <- shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    wellPanel(
      textOutput("selected")
    ),
    DT::dataTableOutput("datatable"),
    actionButton("reset", "Reset")
  )
)

#* Server Definition
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session){
  RV <- reactiveValues(
    row = NULL,
    selection_mode = "single"
  )

  observeEvent(
    input[["datatable_rows_selected"]],
    {
      RV$selection_mode <- "none"

      #* Create a slow event by resampling mtcars a lot.
      set.seed(pi * exp(1))
      fit <- lm(mpg ~ qsec + factor(am), 
                data = mtcars[sample(1:nrow(mtcars), 100000, replace = TRUE), ])
      RV$row <- input[["datatable_rows_selected"]]  
    }
  )

  observeEvent(
    input[["reset"]],
    {
      RV$selection_mode <- "single"
    }
  )

  output$selected <- 
    renderPrint(
      RV$row
    )

  output$datatable <- 
    DT::renderDataTable({
      rownames(mtcars) <- NULL
      DT::datatable(mtcars,
                    selection = list(mode = RV$selection_mode,
                                     target = "row",
                                     selected = RV$row)
      )
    })
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: I wonder if you can dynamically change the `datatable`'s selection mode to `none` during your database access process.

Comment: I've managed to stop the loop, by setting the row selection option to `none`, but I haven't come up with a way to restore row selection without coming back to the original problem (unless I use a button)

Comment: It appears though the new code re-renders the whole table. I tried to find a Javascript method to change the selection mode of `datatables` directly but haven't found any.

Comment: If the thought process is to disable row selection on a click event in the javascript, what is the mechanism to restore row selection?

Comment: I am thinking something like this https://ryouready.wordpress.com/2013/11/20/sending-data-from-client-to-server-and-back-using-shiny/ If there is a javascript variable that controls the selection, you can use Shiny to change it. The thing with Shiny is that when it enters a long calculation, it does not update the UI until the calculation is over, but if it sends data to Javascript, it sends right away.

Comment: Oh, I see now. Send the message to the server with javascript, not to the datatable. I'll read up on that tonight. Thanks.